# Azure function - Error: Install or update .NET to run this application, Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App - No framework were found

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0

I had a problem with the azure function when running on Azure.
My code ran successfully on locally but failed when to run on Azure function.

The project structure is as follows:
My solution have 2 projects: an Azure Function project (project 1) and another project (project 2)

Project 2 was implemented with target framework is net6.0-windows, the .csproj is:
[image]

Project 1 was implemented with the target framework is net6.0, it calls the exe file (which was built from project 2) to get the output, with the .csproj as below:
[image]

The function app project structure is as follows, it runs with .net6-isolated worker process:
[image]

The code will call the exe as below code:
[image]

I publish the project to the azure function with the config as the image below:

[image]

Then, I run the function app and get the error:
[image]

I have tried to convert 2 project are same target framework is with net6.0, but it return missing dll when running, it fails all in local and azure fucntion

Then, I tried to convert 2 project are same target framework is with net6.0-windows, the project now can run on my local, but it failed on Azure function. The azure function auto stop and restart whenever I run it.

Maybe Azure function can not run the net6.0-windows app? Could you all help me to resolve this, or help me have a new approach for my project

Thank you all

Comment: If you could provide sample code what is in both the Function Projects, then it could be better to check and confirm both the projects belongs to same framework/core version - Is that .NET 6 (in-process)?

Comment: Hi @HariKrishna, I have updated some information in my post, the Azure function is .Net 6 - isolated worker process. Could you help me to take a look at this update!

Answer (score 0):

If the Azure Functions Project you're developing only for Windows means, mention the default Target Framework version in the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And then you specify the Windows OS in the Azure Portal (Cloud Running):
[image]

`.net.0-windows` - this type of target framework version is specific to WinForms and WPF Projects as given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms).

For more information on target framework/runtime versions of the Azure Functions supporting different types of OS and languages, refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#locally-developed-application-versions).